# Chanting of Maha Mantra

Tags: krishna, iskcon

Hare Krishna,

Do we need to chant it like Hare "Krishnaa" or Hare "Krishn" . In japa it is Hare "Krishn" but in Keerthan it is Hare "Krishnaa". Please guide

(and same way for Hare "Ramaa")

Namaskar

Comment: The correct pronunciation is 'Hare Krishn' only and not 'Hare Krishnaa'. 'Hare Krishnaa' is a mispronounced version of the mantra, in the same way How Bengali/Odia speaking folks usually mispronounce it as 'Hore Krishno' 'Hore Ramo' while doing Kirtana due to their regional dialect.

Comment: It's 'Hare Kṛṣṇa' (हरे कृष्ण). There is no ā (आ) vowel (svara) in the two terms. 
And it's Rāma (राम) nor Rāmā (रामा). The 'a'(अ) at the end of 'Kṛṣṇa' and 'Rāma' is not pronounced in Hindī properly, unlike in Saṁskṛta. Also, it's hare (हरे) not hāre (हारे). So, the famous mahāmantra in [Kalisantaraṇopaniṣat](https://archive.org/details/108_Upanishads_with_Sanskrit_Commentary_of_Upanishad_Brahma_Yogin/Vaishnava%20Upanishads%20with%20Upanishadbrahman%27s%20commentary%201923/page/n43/mode/2up?view=theater) is -
हरे राम हरे राम राम राम हरे हरे | हरे कृष्ण हरे कृष्ण कृष्ण कृष्ण हरे हरे ||

Comment: Usually, many people in India now too, pronounce the term कृष्ण incorrectly. The slight problem in ऋ is understandable, but they mispronounce both 'ṣ' (ष्) and 'ṇ' (ण) as 'ś' (श्) and 'nā' (ना), respectively. And that is a lot to do, with how Kṛṣṇa is generally written in English. It's written as Krishna, which is quite incorrect. And many english-educated Indians now pronounce the name of Bhagavān similar to how many of their colonial masters pronounced it.

Comment: In śuddha Hindī (and in Avadhī), due to schwa deletion rule, the 'अ' at the end of 'राम' and कृष्ण' is pronounced minimally (or almost dropped), in comparison to pronunciation in Saṁskṛta. Otherwise, the Śuddha Hindī pronunciation is same as that in Saṁskṛta. The problem is that many Hindī speakers too, don't pronounce 'कृष्ण' as per the rules of Hindī. But they pronounce राम correctly, although that's a bit different to pronunciation in Saṁskṛta, as pointed already. When pronouncing either of the terms in a mantra, one should use the Saṁskṛta pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

In Kirtan, it is irrelevant however you chant it. Since what you're doing is more like a song rather than a Mantra.

The pronunciation will always be the same, and, it will be:

हरे राम हरे राम राम राम हरे हरे
हरे कृष्ण हरे कृष्ण कृष्ण कृष्ण हरे हरे

Now, the म in कमल is the same as the म in राम. In other words, it's not Raam. It's Raama. Secondly, अ and आ are the EXACT same sound, but the second one is twice as long as the first. So, it's Raama. Not Raam, not Ram, not Raamaa, not Ramaa. Just Raama.

The pronunciation of अ is like the a in C**a**st (aside). The आ is the same, but twice as long. ए also has a double Maatraa pronunciation, meaning that the 'e' in हरे is twice as long as अ इ उ ऋ ऌ. The रे is supposed to be twice as long as the ह.

The pronunciation of 'Krshna' is what it looks like... It's not Krshnaa and not Krshn.

There's another error with regards to the pronunciation of ऋ in कृष्ण but it will take a long time to correct as you'll need to learn a new placement of the tongue, and you haven't asked for all errors in the pronunciation.